# With DoTween Unity, is there a way to get a callback triggered when a tweening is 50% complete?

Tags: unity-game-engine, dotween

I'm using Unity3D and DoTweeen free version to make some simple animations.
I have been using OnComplete callback a lot, but I'm wondering how I can get a callback that is triggered when half of the animation is completed?
I've checked DoTween website and google, but found no such topic.

Thanks

Comment: hmm good question, I don't know if DoTween has an In-build method, but I think that I will make a double animation, so if your animation is going from point A to B, I will make two animations, one from A to middle of B, throw the callback, and in paralel (cause DoTween allows you to do that) I will make an animation from middle B to B.

Comment: @Lotan thank you, this is also a good idea which is maybe more flexible in some cases.

Answer (score 3):

This should give a basic idea. TweenerCore has a variable called position which is basically the time position of the tween that goes from 0 to duration.

```
float duration = 4.0f; // duration of the animation in seconds
float halfTime = duration * 0.5f; // half time
bool isHalfwayPassed = false;
var tween = transform.DOMove(_targetTransform.position, duration);
tween.OnUpdate(() =>
{
    if(tween.position >= halfTime && !isHalfwayPassed)
    {
         Debug.Log($"Half way passed");
         isHalfwayPassed = true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Cool, good to see some built-in feature that could be leveraged, thanks.